# In what mythologies other than the Basque are the Sun and Moon both female?

Tags: basque

In Basque mythology the Sun goddess, Eki, and the Moon goddess, Ilazki, are sisters.

In what other mythologies are the Sun and Moon both female?

Answer (score 3):

There appear to be many American tribes which have similar views but the question is really much more complicated. It should not be assumed that all languages have gender, that gender implies sex, or that the moon or the sun at different occasions is the same entity, etc. etc. A classic 10 page paper by Claude Lévi-Strauss *The Sex of the Sun and Moon* ([Structural anthropology v.2](https://archive.org/details/structuralanthro00lv) c.1963) has treated the question in a most enlightening way.

> sometimes in one myth to the other in the same group the sun and the
>   moon are  two women or two men (p.219)

Comment: Every reproduced human culture has gender. If one didn't (how would it reproduce?), it would not be an answer to this q. Gender is the same as sex, despite the extremely recent fashionable propagation of ideas to the contrary. As for the ontological point regarding celestial bodies, the notion of "the moon at different occasions" implies a notion of "moon" over and above different occasions, which is what the question asks about. The question asks for specific mythologies, not for a reference to their existence. I will look for whether the Levi-Strauss chapter contains specific references.

Comment: I don't think the statement that "sometimes in one myth to the other in the same group the sun and the moon are two women or two men" treats the question "In what mythologies are the Sun and Moon both female?" in any way, enlightening or otherwise.

Comment: Sancta Simplicitas!